# How to remove thousands of unused non-composite, automatic generated, index of google datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

The process to create/remove composite index using cloud datastore emulator is straightforward ([here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/#the_development_workflow_using_gcloud), [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#starting_the_emulator) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/datastore/start)), but I couldn't find any means to exclude literally hundreds (or even thousands) non-composite index that datastore generates automatically.

Is there any method to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Note: I didn't use the standalone emulator yet, only the datastore emulation bundled inside the local development server for standard environment GAE apps, but I presume the implementation is similar.

The emulator replicates the real datastore behaviour. And the datastore creates these built-in indexes for all indexed properties. From [Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes):

> **Built-in indexes**
>
> By default, Cloud Datastore automatically predefines an index for each
>   property of each entity kind. These single property indexes are
>   suitable for simple types of queries.

The built-in indexes are also used for the datastore/admin GQL queries and for sorting entities in the datastore admin pages, both on GCP and in local emulation.

The only way to prevent creation of built-in indexes is to mark the respective properties as unindexed (or excluded). From [Excluded properties](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#unindexed_properties):

> If you know you will never have to filter or sort on a particular
>   property, you can tell Cloud Datastore not to maintain index entries
>   for that property by excluding it from indexes. This lowers the cost
>   of running your application by reducing the [storage size](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/storage-size) needed
>   for index entries. An entity with an excluded property behaves as if
>   the property were not set: queries with a filter or sort order on the
>   excluded property will never match that entity.
>
> **Note:** If a property appears in a composite index, then excluding the property will disable it in the composite index. For example,
>   suppose that an entity has properties `priority` and `done` and that
>   you want to create an index able to satisfy queries like `WHERE
>   priority = 4 AND done = FALSE`. Also suppose that you don't care about
>   the queries `WHERE priority = 4` and `WHERE done = FALSE`. If you
>   exclude `priority` from indexes and create an index for `priority` and
>   `done`, Cloud Datastore will not create index entries for the
>   `priority` and `done` index and so the `WHERE priority = 4 AND done =
>   FALSE` query won't work. For Cloud Datastore to create entries for the
>   `priority` and `done` indexes, both `priority` and `done` must be
>   indexed.

Also note that excluded properties can't be used in projection queries.

Comment: Thanks Dan. My problem with this approach is that my JSONs are standard {property: value} and it seems that I would need to add a new layer like { {property: name}, {value: value}, excludedFromIndexes: true}} which would demand me to change basically all the submit/retrieve datastore operations and deal with the complexity to transform one JSON standard to another. It is disappointing how bad is the solution google gave us.